# setting/getting/checking multiple cookies generated by user-input (textboxes) in one go

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I'm bashing my head against a wall and hoping someone can help.  I've got to include three text boxes for users to enter values for the following cookies: name, city, and hobby.  Then I need to use a single button with an onclick event that will call the function to create the three cookies (with values). I need a further function that will check the existence of each cookie when the page is accessed. If one or more of the cookies is not set, an alert box should notify the user to set the unset cookie(s). If all three cookies are set, the alert box should display the contents of each cookie.

Where I am seriously hung up (I think) is on how to pass the value from the textbox and a corresponding key as arguments to a generic setCookie function.  W3schools gives a code template for creating, getting and checking cookies (below) but I've no idea how to actually implement that with setting the cookies via user-input or setting all 3 at once!  I am seriously thick as a brick, it seems.

My html textboxes and submit button:

```
Please enter your name: <input type = "text" name = "name" id = "name"> <br>
                Please enter your city: <input type = "text" name = "city" id = "school"><br>
                Please enter a hobby: <input type = "text" name = "hobby" id = "hobby"><br>
                <button id = "btn12" onclick = "createCookies()">Create cookies</button></p>
                </form>
```

W3schools cookie template:

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var user = getCookie("username");
    if (user != "") {
        alert("Welcome again " + user);
    } else {
        user = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
        if (user != "" && user != null) {
            setCookie("username", user, 365);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be so appreciated!  I've googled everything I can find on setting cookies in Javascript and can't make heads or tails of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely possible. I made an example using your HTML above. It's a bit long but I'll include it here as StackOverflow expects.

HTML:

```
<p>
  Please enter your name:
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  <br> Please enter your city:
  <input type="text" name="city" id="city">
  <br> Please enter a hobby:
  <input type="text" name="hobby" id="hobby">
  <br>
  <button id="btn12">Create cookies</button>
</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('btn12').addEventListener('click', createCookies);

// jsfiddle runs code after page loads -- in other environments
// run this on page load
document.getElementById("name").value = getCookie("name");
document.getElementById("city").value = getCookie("city");
document.getElementById("hobby").value = getCookie("hobby");

function createCookies(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();

  setCookie('name', document.getElementById("name").value);
  setCookie('city', document.getElementById("city").value);
  setCookie('hobby', document.getElementById("hobby").value);
}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  exdays = exdays || 30; // default to 30 days
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
  }
  return "";
}
```

You can add some values in the inputs, click on the 'Create cookies' button and then reload the page and the inputs should have the values you entered before.

How does it work? Well we need to set the input values on load. There is some code to do that -- these lines:

```
document.getElementById("name").value = getCookie("name");
document.getElementById("city").value = getCookie("city");
document.getElementById("hobby").value = getCookie("hobby");
```

If there is no value, the input will be set to nothing so no problem there.

On click, we run this code:

```
function createCookies(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();

  setCookie('name', document.getElementById("name").value);
  setCookie('city', document.getElementById("city").value);
  setCookie('hobby', document.getElementById("hobby").value);
}
```

That calls through to your `setCookie` function -- I modified it so it defaults to 30 days (the 3rd parameter) just to make things a bit easier.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z7ayebpr/

Comment: Cymen that is one beautiful bit of code, thank you!!!  It works a charm.  I'm printing it and keeping it to study and as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Cymen's code above definitely worked for me!!

I wanted to add an additional note for anyone creating cookies for the first time. Most likely you're initially setting this up locally, which is completely fine. Just know, if you are using Chrome, you won't be able to see locally stored cookies in the browser as you test/debug.

If you are using Chrome, think about switching to Firefox for this kind of debugging.

You can see your cookie in local storage by clicking options in the Firefox browser (top right), then selecting "Web Developer", then selecting "Storage Inspector." Firefox dev tools will then open and navigate you to storage. Expand cookies, select your file and you should see the cookie(s) you've just created.

This makes it much easier to develop and optimize your cookies before pushing your code to your dev branch and turning buggy code live.

(Don't mind the crappy markups in the example image)[image]